# how to average groups of elements in a list in R?

Tags: r, list, average

In R, I have list of 10 elements,such as:

```
n <- c(5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6)
```

I want to create another list which will have 2 elements where each element will be the average of 5-elements in the previous list. So, other list should look like as follows:

```
5,6
```

Is there a quick way to do that in R? What i want is a list which gives me the average of first X element, the average of second X element and so on.. In the example, initial list has 10 elements and I want to group them by 5. So I am trying to calculate a list where first element is the mean of first 5 elements, and the second element is the mean of last 5 elements.

Comment: so it should be 10 elements or 2?

Comment: `ave(x, (seq_along(x)-1) %/% 5)` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, your original list has 500 names. Here's an approach:

```
x <- runif(500)
list_x <- split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/50))

# find the mean in each group of 50
colMeans(as.data.frame(list_x))
```

for 10 elements:

```
y <- c(rep(5, 5), rep(6, 5))

list_y <- split(y, ceiling(seq_along(y)/5))
colMeans(as.data.frame(list_y))
```

Comment: well, actually i have 500 elements and i want to calculate average of each 50 element.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: For a list like this: [1] 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6, it gives me [1] 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5, but I what i want is [1] 5 6 First item is the mean of first 5 elements, second is the mean of last 5 elements

Comment: But you just said you had 500 elements in your list-it's not clear what you're after.

Comment: I've edited my answer again: I think `colMeans` is what we needed here.

Comment: In my real system, I do have 500 elements but if it is not working on a simple example, then it's gonna be really difficult to debug for me

Answer (score 3):

Cast your vector of values

```
x = rnorm(50 * 10)
```

into a matrix and take the column means

```
colMeans(matrix(x, 50))
```

More generally, create a vector that describes how the data is to be partitioned

```
f = rep(seq_len(10), each=50)
```

`split()` your data, `lapply()` the function to each group, and combine (`unlist()` in this case) the results

```
unlist(lapply(split(x, f), mean))
```

Do this in two (e.g., `sapply(split(x, f), mean)`) or one (e.g., `tapply()`, `by()`, `ave()`) steps.

Comment: it gives me an incorrect answer :s

Comment: @wthimdh - Then perhaps you should clarify the question.  It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish (according to at least four people that have voted to close this question).

Comment: @wthimdh for your example, this would be `colMeans(matrix(x, ncol = length(x) / 5))` since you want chunks of 5

Comment: @rawr thanks, finally i have the list ^^